# SQL Operand Should contain 1 colums PHPMYAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

i create this code

```
 INSERT INTO `ordini`(`ora`, `nome`, `indirizzo`, `numero`, `help`,`ID`,`fattorino`,`dreturn`,`flag`) 
VALUES ((SELECT `ora`, `nome`, `indirizzo`, `numero`, `help`,`ID` FROM test.dbconsegne WHERE ID = 2),'STRING','CURRENT_TIMESTAMP','0');
```

and when i try to Execute the query , The PHPMyAdmin push out this error 
Operand should contain 1 colum(s)
why? it's not correct
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need `VALUES`, take it out

```
INSERT INTO `ordini`(`ora`, `nome`, `indirizzo`, `numero`, `help`,`ID`,`fattorino`,`dreturn`,`flag`) 
SELECT `ora`, `nome`, `indirizzo`, `numero`, `help`,`ID`,'STRING',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'0' FROM test.dbconsegne WHERE ID = 2
```